# Wrong count in PowerBI-service but not in Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I've used "count" function on how many jobs a supplier has done in PowerBI Desktop, it works perfect in both Matrix and Table. But when I publish it in PowerBI Service, it gives me wrong value  in Matrix but right one in Table. In the Matrix it just says "1" on every supplier, but when I open it it gives me the right amount:

[image]

Red = Supplier

Yellow  = Jobs

Thanks for help

Comment: add some sample data and your measures etc to your question...

Answer (score 0):

I changed count to distinct count and now it works!